# How to download a file from an aspx page after requesting it via POST using R

Tags: asp.net, r

I would like to download the excel file for a given date from this page:

http://www.mcxindia.com/SitePages/BhavCopy.aspx

The way it works is:

1. Request excel file by posting date
2. This returns a page with a snapshot of the file and a function to return an excel url link
3. Invoke the function to generate the url to the excel file
4. Download the excel file

Usually, I post code while asking questions, but in this case I have simply no idea where to start.

Comment: use Developer Tools to watch the transactions, copy the curl statement from the one you need and mimic it in `httr`